# How to preview my GRUB menu without rebooting?

Tags: grub2

I want to change my default boot OS in GRUB2.  But the only way I know of seeing the order of the OS I want in the GRUB menu is doing a reboot and seeing the menu displayed.

In `grub.cfg` there are many more `menuentry` lines than actual choices in the GRUB menu, so I can't identify in that file the one I want.

Is there any place where the actually displayed menu is stored so that I can see it without having to reboot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note: **This answer was originally written when legacy grub was used.  It has been updated to work with GRUB2.**

I believe that `grub2-emu` should work for you. In a terminal, execute:

```bash
sudo apt install grub2-emu && grub2-emu
```

[image]

[See here](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/06/how-to-preview-grub-bootloader-changes.html) for more information.

Be aware: **You have to set focus to the terminal in which you started the emulator to be able to do inputs!** The window of the emulator self will not react to any inputs at all.

Comment: Yep, this is the answer. Thanks! By the way, how do you close the grub-emu window?  When I open it, my keyboard becomes unresponsive and the only thing that works is closing the terminal window from which I run grub-emu.

Comment: @ARX Have you tried the `reboot` or `exit` command in GRUB?

Comment: Can't. No keyboard. While grub-emu's window is focused, it's dead.

Comment: NOTE: Type in the ORIGINAL shell window (where you start it from), not the "display"-window. After `c` (for grub prompt) and then `exit` the Shell-prompt is missing, type `reset` (a command from 'terminfo') and ENTER to get it back.

Comment: That last comment should be added to the answer IMHO.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine, but make sure the run the grub-emu as sudo. Without sudo, grub-emu would just jump to the grub commandline, which won't be as useful.

Comment: Pity that not available for Redhat Linux :-(

Comment: ℹ️ In `grub.cfg` you can control if the emulator launches in the terminal or in a **separate window** with the command `terminal_output [output]`. Where `output` can be `console`, `gfxterm` or both.

Answer (score 6):

[image: grub2-theme-preview__gutsblack-archlinux]

You can install [grub2-theme-preview](https://github.com/hartwork/grub2-theme-preview), which is a PyPi package. It uses QEMU and seems to work well for testing grub themes and this without having to restart after every change.

[It's also available directly from AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/grub2-theme-preview/), which is the version I used, as I'm using Manjaro.

It requires the following non-PyPi dependencies ([see README.md](https://github.com/hartwork/grub2-theme-preview/blob/master/README.md) for links, more details and potential updates):

- grub-mkrescue of GRUB 2 (package grub-common on Debian and Ubuntu)
- QEMU — hypervisor that performs hardware virtualization
- OVMF — EFI bios image for use with QEMU
- mtools — collection of utilities to access MS-DOS
- xorriso of libisoburn — frontend which enables creation and expansion of the ISO format
- And python / pip, of course

To install, run the following command:

`pip install --user grub2-theme-preview`

Once installed you can run `grub2-theme-preview /path/to/your/theme/directory` from the terminal to launch it (more on usage [here.](https://github.com/hartwork/grub2-theme-preview#usage))

Note: if you have any custom configs, e.g. custom.cfg or, say, liveiso.cfg, that you pull into your grub.cfg separately, thanks to the script in /etc/grub.d/41_custom, for example, their entries may not show up, in which case you'll need to use the newly added --add flag. Your command might look like the following, with --add TARGET=/SOURCE for each custom config you want added:

```
grub2-theme-preview --verbose --grub-cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg --add /boot/grub/custom.cfg=/boot/grub/custom.cfg --add /boot/grub/gpu-switcher.cfg=/boot/grub/gpu-switcher.cfg --add /boot/grub/liveiso.cfg=/boot/grub/liveiso.cfg /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro
```

More context here: https://github.com/hartwork/grub2-theme-preview/issues/29#issuecomment-980802808

---

You can also check out [the answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599208/how-to-list-grubs-menuentries-in-command-line) if you want something a bit more terminal centric and only needing to see order. This awk command, for example, will give you entries and sub entries as well:

`awk -F\' '/(^|| )nuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg|cat -n|awk '{print $1-1,$1="",$0}'`

[*Source*](https://askubuntu.com/a/999550/403296)

---

I like these options better than `grub-emu`, as that seems to have an issue closing, without having to close your terminal completely, as mentioned in the comments of that answer. Plus, grub2-theme-preview will actually show you the theme (although it does require more dependency setup) and the awk command is quick and easy; perhaps add it as an alias if you use it often so you don't have to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

grub-emu works fine for me. I simply use the following command to kill `grub-emu` if it gets stuck.

```bsh
ps -a | grep grub-emu | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Why not just `killall -9 grub-emu`?